# Objective C, how to query if an object is of a certain class

Tags: objective-c, derived-class

I am deriving from TableViewCell. When i query the table view about an index path it returns a UITableViewCell. How do i find if this object is one of my custom type "CustomCell"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ([cell isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]]) {
    [(CustomCell*)cell customCellMethod];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ([cell isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]]) {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As always in object-oriented design, trying to use an instance's class identity is a code smell and should raise a flag. What exactly are you trying to do with your custom cell? Perhaps someone can suggest a better approach.

No mater what, it's much better design to depend on an interface (a `@protocol` in Objective-C speak) than a class as it helps to decouple your design. Define a `@protocol` with the relevant API you need and have your `CustomCell` implement that protocol. In your code you can then test:

```
if([cell conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyCellProtocol)]) {
  //...
}
```

rather than testing for class identity.

If you only need a single method, you can use `[cell respondsToSelector:@selector(myMethod)]`.

Comment: I think the use case is pretty clear in this case.  Especially with the way ObjectiveC typing works.  You have a table view filled with cells of various subclasses of `UITableViewCell`, and you ask for one with `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]`.  That table view method only promises to return an instance of `UITableViewCell`, and the only way to know if you have a subclass of that cell is to test its class.  You could create a protocol, but  you would be putting most of your custom cell methods in it anyway, making things a lot more verbose for little apparent benefit.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two methods you could use here. The one you probably want is [`isKindOfClass:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass:), but there is another method called [`isMemberOfClass:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isMemberOfClass:) and this will only return `YES` if the receiver is an instance of the provided class, not an instance of a subclass.

For example, if `DerivedClass` is a subclass of `BaseClass`, then here are the outcomes of each method:

```
BOOL isKind = [aDerivedInstance isKindOfClass:[BaseClass class]]; // YES
BOOL isMember = [aDerivedInstance isMemberOfClass:[BaseClass class]]; // NO
```